# where is the setting.py file in Mezzaine.account django app?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I spent nearly two hours trying to locate the `setting` file for `Mezzaine.account` app from `github`.

The `admin.py` from `accounts app` does import of `settings`, but I cannot locate this file.
`https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/accounts/admin.py`
and it does `from mezzanine.conf import settings` but I could not locate this file.
I am trying to use [Account verification feature](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/user-accounts.html) by using `ACCOUNTS_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED`. but I am unable to locate this in the source code.
please guide me where the source code for this implementation is available. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reading the documentation, so you're off to a great start! If you continue down this path, you'll find the section on how Mezzanine structures all of its settings:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html

(note, this is quite different from what one of the comments above describes)